# Axios response data is reversed

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch

Here it's my code

```
const response = await axios.get(url, { headers, params });
const { data } = await response;
console.log(data);
```

The log result is:

[image]

But the network devtools of the browser shows:

[image]

There you can see that the results list of the log and the network devtools is reversed. The right order should be the one that the browser is showing (I also printed it in the back-end)

Comment: If you have the count variable, why don't you just loop through it and make a new array putting elements from last to first? Of course I'm saying this if you do not find a better solution

Comment: But this is an strange behaviour, I can't ensure that the response will always be reversed.